# Detect time taken to type into Autocomplete field and auto select if only one item found

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, barcode

Right, I've nearly found what I'm after but not quite.

Given a simple jQUery call to Autocomplete

```
    $(".autoItem").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var itemNumber = id.replace('item', '');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: "jsonOut/products.aspx",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#price' + itemNumber).val(ui.item.price);
                $('#id' + itemNumber).val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
    });
```

Which works lovely, I am now over complicating it as usual due to my application.

This is for a web form for making sales in a shop. The text box can be populated by two methods:

A) Simply typing as normal.
B) Scanning a code with a bar code scanner.

In case A, everything's fine, autocomplete works exactly as autocomplete was intended.

In case B though, I have two issues:

1. I need to be able to detect that this entry is from a scanner, so that the code behind knows to search the barcode field of my database, not item titles. Clearly the browser's not gonna know that, so the only way I can think is to do it by time. The scanner will populate the field faster than anyone can type.
2. Once a result has been generated by AutoComplete with a barcode, it will clearly only return one result, so in cases where only one result is returned, I want it to auto-select that result and run it's select function populating the other fields as required.

(the bar code scanner has a TAB terminator, so after scanning it immediately blurs the text field an moves on to the next one)

Would something like this be possible?

If someone could help with issue in isolation, that'd be cool. I have looked at https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js for point B, but couldn't get it to work.

NOTE: If the worst comes to the worst, I could detect scanned entries by using `isNumeri`c in the code behind, BUT, some codes we scan are not numeric, clearly proper UPC codes are, but we have some items with barcodes generated from product SKUs, these might not be numeric.

Comment: why not setup barcode reader to send a carriage return (press enter key) after barcode read?  That should immediately submit the form and any AJAX autocomplete stuff should be irrelevant.

Comment: The form might not be ready to submit. Other data has to be completed, such as customer name, or other products, this isn't necessarily for a single item sale. jQuery creates a next item field after the first sale item detail fields are complete.

Comment: My initial impression is I don't think this [web page/app] is the right approach for an bar code scanning app because it assumes the browser and the input field is focused (which is more difficult to maintain outside of the web app). You could try creating a browser plug-in since it seems your app is very specific to your customer and building a web service so you could just interacting with it that way.

Comment: The focus is OK, I get your point, but initial setup of the form ensures it is focused when required. Bar code scanning is not the default method of entering the form anyway, hence the use of AutoComplete for a text entry, otherwise I'd post the barcode back and populate price etc directly per item.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `delay` option for jQueryUI autocomplete? http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-delay

This should separate man from machine and only do autocomplete for humans.

---

As far as it not being a single item sale...

Capture the carriage return event on the barcode fields using javascript and prevent form submission by returning `false`.

Comment: also, when you prevent carriage return, go ahead and move focus to next barcode input field.

Comment: That's almost there... Except I do need it to submit something to pull prices from the database to do `$('#price' + itemNumber).val(ui.item.price);` which populates the form field. I could do that after the form submission, but it useful for sales staff for prices to populate as they scan bar codes. I'd need to detect if there was an attempt to submit the form too quickly which would call a different AJAX function to pull prices. That would work, but I feel there's probably something using less code to force select of the first (only) item returned by autocomplete if field is filled in fast.

Comment: Are you still stuck at this point? Or do you have enough to make a working solution?

Comment: Sorry, had to do other jobs today. I'll be back on this Monday and will try the advice given... Watch this space...!

Answer (score 0):

Right...

I'm not keen on answering my own question, but the the guys that helped with this, thanks so much. I didn't quite get exactly what I needed, but as always you pointed me in the right direction.

Turned out really simple in the end... after hours of fiddling around with focus() blur() change() and all kinds of identifiers!

@Teddy your tips and answer pretty much did it.

The bar code readers default to have a carriage return as the terminator that the produce immediately after scanning. I wasn't sure if it would work, but the browser does pick this up as an Enter keypress, so I can do:

```
$('.findProduct').live('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) { 
        // call a load function to get details from bar code
    };
});

$('.findProduct').live('focus', function () { findProduct() }); // findProduct is the AutoComplete function
```

As @Teddy, you said, the delay function in AutoComplete ensures that this won't have any effect on AutoComplete, as soon as the scanner sends the Enter terminator I can have jQuery call the data that I need.

When typing manually into the box, AutoComplete does it's thing as normal.

So, next bit of advice, do you think I should disable the Enter key after Autocomplete has done it's thing to avoid confusion, and similarly, disable the AutoComplete function by some means (not yet worked out)?

EDIT: I should say, the form no longer has a submit button, submit will be done by a  clickable div or image or something.